# Can I define an overloaded '+' that add a double and an array in C#

Tags: c#, overloading, operator-keyword

I want to define a '+' so that I can add a double and a double array:

```
double[] x = {1.2, 1.4, 1.8};
double[] y = new double[3];
y = x + 0.3;
```

The result y should equals to 
    {1.5, 1.7, 2.1}. 
That is, each element of x is added 0.3.
I tried, but got compile error. Does that mean there is no way to accomplish this task? '+' can only be applied to two operands with the same type?

Comment: O_O `compile error. Does that mean there is no way to accomplish this task?` No. A compile error does not make a task impossible. You're going to run into a lot of those, trust me.

Comment: Quoting the spec: *User-defined operator declarations always require at least one of the parameters to be of the class or struct type that contains the operator declaration. Thus, it is not possible for a user-defined operator to have the same signature as a predefined operator.* So no, you can't do this.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
double[] x = { 1.2, 1.4, 1.8 };
double[] y = x.Select(r => r + 0.3).ToArray();
```

Which would add `0.3` to each element in `x`, but if you want to overload `+` operator then look at [operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Also if you don't need to clone the data you can use Array.ForEach

Comment: I would recommend @Habib's answer before overloading. This code is very clear in its intent. Overloaded operators can be confusing to anyone who reads the code after you.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I quite like the solution suggested by @Habib. For the sake of variety, I am going to outline an alternative solution.

If you find yourself working quite a lot with vectors and matrices (i.e. one and two dimensional arrays), then you might find many of the extension methods in the Accord.Math library useful. You can install it with NuGet like so:

```
Install-Package Accord.Math
```

Then add a `using` declaration to your class to bring the extension methods into play

```
using Accord.Math;
```

Now you can add a scalar to every element in a vector (array) like so:

```
double[] x = {1.2, 1.4, 1.8};
double[] y = x.Add(0.3);
Console.WriteLine(y.ToString(DefaultMatrixFormatProvider.CurrentCulture));
```

which outputs

```
1.5 
1.7 
2.1
```